# UI Swiping Animation in Animator - Debug in Unity Game Engine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I'm making a maths game that swipes left or right whenever a user gets an answer correct in Unity
but when I test the game the swipe happens automatically instead of waiting for user input, despite setting the parameters for a swipe to happen only when a user swipes more than >10 on the x-axis.

I've tried everything to debug this but I can't figure out. Hopefully, someone could help me please.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;


using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class MathGameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject answer1, answer2; // UI elements for answers
    public Animator answer1Animator, answer2Animator; // Animators for the answers

    private Vector2 startTouchPosition, endTouchPosition;
    private bool isSwiping = false;
    private float swipeThreshold = 50f; // Minimum swipe distance to trigger the animation

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            switch (touch.phase)
            {
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    startTouchPosition = touch.position;
                    isSwiping = true;
                    break;

                case TouchPhase.Ended:
                    endTouchPosition = touch.position;
                    if (isSwiping)
                    {
                        FinishSwipe();
                        isSwiping = false;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    void FinishSwipe()
    {
        Vector2 swipeDirection = endTouchPosition - startTouchPosition;

        if (Mathf.Abs(swipeDirection.x) > swipeThreshold)
        {
            if (swipeDirection.x > 0)
            {
                // Swipe Right detected
                answer1Animator.SetTrigger("swipeRight");
                answer2Animator.SetTrigger("swipeRight");
            }
            else
            {
                // Swipe Left detected
                answer1Animator.SetTrigger("swipeLeft");
                answer2Animator.SetTrigger("swipeLeft");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's the code.

The animation works, so I'm doing something write in the animation and animator parts.
But something is going wrong somewhere.

My idle state is idle. Nothing is happening.
My transition has a condition and I reference it in my code.
So, the swipe should happen based on the condition which is a user swiping on the x-axis a movement >10.
But the swipe happens automatically every time, rather than waiting for a user input.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it would be easier to see if you set your Inspector to the normal mode (not debug)

Comment: also how many instances of this script are in your scene? in the one you show the animators are not referenced ...

Comment: @derHugo Just two instances, I believe.

One for answer1
and another for answer2

so when i click on answer1 on the hierachy, it deals with the leftSwipe state
and answer2, it deals with the rightSwipe state


if that's what you mean.

Comment: shouldn't there be only one single instance of this manager script?

Comment: @derHugo sorry, i'm very self taught and all the terms are confusing me because I didn't learn them properly
Can I share you the project file and you take a look?
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/fc0e44f89ccd16c87965774b93ace7ff20240111175533/3ca07c

Comment: I've checked it out .. but tbh I'm unsure what I should do with it .. there seem a couple of references missing .. you indeed have two instances of your `MathGameController` .. one on the `answer1` and one on the `answer2` .. they will both be executed at the same time ... however none of the animators seems to be actually referenced anywhere except in another script `MathsProblems` .. so a bit hard to tell what exactly is supposed to happen here

Comment: @derHugo Based on your feedback, I updated my knowledge of gameobjects and components, consolidated the instances of MathGameController into 1, and updated certain components that had conflicting name schemes.

I removed the swipe animation aspect to the game too because, even after cleaning up everything and still trying to debug, I couldn't figure it out. 

The good news is the game now works with simple touch inputs and the animation I do have is for the colour changing when an answer is correct. Thanks for the help, derHugo!